# Error - unable to compute hourly averages using timeAverage() function

Tags: r, openair

I am trying to calculate the hourly averages (January 2014) of a dataset using `timeAverage()` function. The command looks like follows:

```
AQHr <- timeAverage(my_data, avg.time = "hour", data.thresh = 0,
                       statistic = "mean", percentile = NA,
                       start.date = "2014-01-01", end.date = "2014-01-31",
                       interval = "hour", vector.ws = FALSE)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
Can not automatically convert from POSIXct, POSIXt to Date in column "date".
```

Looks like something is terribly wrong with the `date` column in the data frame. Column `date` is in the following format:

```
> str(my_data$date)
Date[1:192840], format: "1993-12-31" "1994-01-01" "1994-01-01" "1994-01-01" 
"1994-01-01" "1994-01-01" "1994-01-01" "1994-01-01" "1994-01-01" ...
```

Can someone suggest how to fix this error?

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is sample `my_data`:

```
Sr       day      month    year     hour      date          my_value
1        1        1       1994      1         31/12/1993    70.49488
2        1        1       1994      2         01/01/1994    41.3616
3        1        1       1994      3         01/01/1994    30.99245
4        1        1       1994      4         01/01/1994    30.32162
5        1        1       1994      5         01/01/1994    29.91912
6        1        1       1994      6         01/01/1994    26.94829
7        1        1       1994      7         01/01/1994    28.90329
8        1        1       1994      8         01/01/1994    34.25078
9        1        1       1994      9         01/01/1994    30.32162
10       1        1       1994      10        01/01/1994    26.81412
11       1        1       1994      11        01/01/1994    26.69912
12       1        1       1994      12        01/01/1994    28.00245
13       1        1       1994      13        01/01/1994    28.88412
14       1        1       1994      14        01/01/1994    31.01162
15       1        1       1994      15        01/01/1994    26.71829
16       1        1       1994      16        01/01/1994    29.84245
17       1        1       1994      17        01/01/1994    43.33576
18       1        1       1994      18        01/01/1994    39.21494
19       1        1       1994      19        01/01/1994    33.33078
20       1        1       1994      20        01/01/1994    34.11661
21       1        1       1994      21        01/01/1994    36.07161
22       1        1       1994      22        01/01/1994    36.76161
23       1        1       1994      23        01/01/1994    38.4291
24       1        1       1994      24        01/01/1994    34.80661
```

with:

```
> str(my_data)
'data.frame':   192840 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ day      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ month    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ year     : int  1994 1994 1994 1994 1994 1994 1994 1994 1994 1994 ...
 $ hour     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ date     : Date, format: "1993-12-31" "1994-01-01" "1994-01-01" "1994-01-01" ...
 $ my_value : num  70.5 41.4 31 30.3 29.9 ...
```

Comment: Can you supply a sample data frame?

Comment: @stuski: Just updated the question with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The package "openair" use the format POSIXct for date.

Change format with:

```
library(dplyr)
AQHr <- AQHr %>% 
  mutate(date = paste(year, month, day, hour, sep = "-")) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(strptime(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d-%H", tz = "")))
```